# Why function works properly without specifying parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In the below code, I don't understand why `download_progress_hook` works without passing parameters when it is called from within the `maybe_download` method.

The definition of `download_progress_hook` states that there are three parameters that have to be passed: `count, blockSize, totalSize`.
But, when the `download_progress_hook` is called from `maybe_download` there are no parameters passed. Why doesn't it fail?

Here is the full code:

```
url = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/books1000/'
last_percent_reported = None
data_root = '.' # Change me to store data elsewhere

def download_progress_hook(count, blockSize, totalSize):
  """A hook to report the progress of a download. This is mostly intended for users with
  slow internet connections. Reports every 5% change in download progress.
  """
  global last_percent_reported
  percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)

  if last_percent_reported != percent:
    if percent % 5 == 0:
      sys.stdout.write("%s%%" % percent)
      sys.stdout.flush()
    else:
      sys.stdout.write(".")
      sys.stdout.flush()

    last_percent_reported = percent

def maybe_download(filename, expected_bytes, force=False):
  """Download a file if not present, and make sure it's the right size."""
  dest_filename = os.path.join(data_root, filename)
  if force or not os.path.exists(dest_filename):
    print('Attempting to download:', filename) 
    filename, _ = urlretrieve(url + filename, dest_filename, reporthook=download_progress_hook)
    print('\nDownload Complete!')
  statinfo = os.stat(dest_filename)
  if statinfo.st_size == expected_bytes:
    print('Found and verified', dest_filename)
  else:
    raise Exception(
      'Failed to verify ' + dest_filename + '. Can you get to it with a browser?')
  return dest_filename

train_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_large.tar.gz', 247336696)
test_filename = maybe_download('notMNIST_small.tar.gz', 8458043)
```

Comment: You mean in `urlretrieve(..., reporthook=download_progress_hook`)`? The function is **not being called there**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I get everything, but the point where the function `download_progress_hook` gets called from within function `maybe_download`

That's where you went wrong. The function is *not being called*. It is only being referenced. There is no `(...)` call expression there.

Python functions are first-class objects, you can pass them around or assign them to other names:

```
>>> def foo(bar):
...     return bar + 1
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x100e20410>
>>> spam = foo
>>> spam
<function foo at 0x100e20410>
>>> spam(5)
6
```

Here `spam` is another reference to the function object `foo`. I can call that function object through that other name too.

So the following expression:

```
urlretrieve(
    url + filename, dest_filename,
    reporthook=download_progress_hook)
```

doesn't *call* `download_progress_hook`. It merely gives that function object to the `urlretrieve()` function, and it is *that code* that'll call `download_progress_hook` somewhere (passing in the required arguments).

From the [`URLOpener.retrieve` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.URLopener.retrieve) (which ultimately handles that hook):

> If *reporthook* is given, it must be a function accepting three numeric parameters: A chunk number, the maximum size chunks are read in and the total size of the download (-1 if unknown). It will be called once at the start and after each chunk of data is read from the network.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib.request
import os

class Progress:
def __init__(self):
    self.old_percent = 0

def download_progress_hook(self, count, blockSize, totalSize):
    percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)
    if percent > self.old_percent:
        self.old_percent = percent
        os.system('cls')
        print(percent, '%')
    if percent == 100:
        os.system('cls')
        print('done!')

title = 'title'
url_mp4 = 'https://url'
progress = Progress()
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_mp4, title + '.mp4', reporthook=progress.download_progress_hook)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like ICEBURG's answer, but os.system('cls') isn't portable so I made a progress bar with ASCII:

```py
class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old_percent = 0
        print('_' * 50)

    def download_progress_hook(self, count, blockSize, totalSize):
        percent = int(count * blockSize * 100 / totalSize)
        if percent >= 2 + self.old_percent:
            self.old_percent = percent
            # print(percent, '%')
            print('>', end='')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        if percent == 100:
            print('\ndone!')
```

It outputs:

```
__________________________________________________
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```