# how python urlretrieve reporthook function handle the input argument

Tags: progress, urlretrieve

I am reading some codes which work nicely. In the codes, it use *urlretrieve* to download file from web. While it's downloading it can also report how much has been downloaded.

The urlretrieve calling is like below:

```
urlretrieve(url + filename, dest_filename, reporthook=download_progress_hook)
```

And the *download_progress_hook()* is defined as below:

```
def download_progress_hook(count, blockSize, totalSize):
    print(count, blockSize, totalSize)
```

When I gave some url and started to download sth. from web, it kept reporting *count,blocksize* and *totalsize* as below output

```
0 8192 8458043
1 8192 8458043
2 8192 8458043
3 8192 8458043
4 8192 8458043
5 8192 8458043
6 8192 8458043
7 8192 8458043
```

The python documents described as "The hook will be passed three arguments; a count of blocks transferred so far, a block size in bytes, and the total size of the file. The third argument may be -1 on older FTP servers which do not return a file size in response to a retrieval request."
This looks strange for me. My understanding is when *urlretrieve* functions was calling, it used the output of *download_progress_hook* function as the input to *urlretrieve* and named it as *reporthook* variable.
But according to the results of this code, it looks like whenever *urlretrieve* is called with 3rd arguments, which should be defined as function, the *urlretrieve* will feedback the 3 information to that function. I know from other functions in urllib, we might get the file size by checking the header file. But I don't understand how this whole mechanism worked here. How the variable passed into function *download_progress_hook*. According to output, it's like the *download_progress_hook* function are keeping running during the lifetime of *urlretrieve*. This might be some concepts in python programming or urllib? Appreciating any thoughts and instructions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why function works properly without specifying parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370284/why-function-works-properly-without-specifying-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

This is late reply but since i also was reading about this answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370284/why-function-works-properly-without-specifying-parameters/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370284/why-function-works-properly-without-specifying-parameters)

summary:

> urlretrieve doesn't call download_progress_hook. It merely gives that function object to the urlretrieve() function as reference and it is that code that'll call download_progress_hook somewhere (passing in the required arguments).